# Cannot upgrade feathers CLI

Tags: feathersjs

I am desperately trying to upgrade the feathers CLI from 3.9 to 4.x+, however

```
npm remove -g @feathersjs/cli  <-- even after doing this I still can use feathersCLI? (feathers -V)
npm install -g @feathersjs/cli  <-- should install latest
feathers -V <--- 3.9 ?!
```

How do I manually remove it?

Os: Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

okay, had to do it manually. I had to alter the config myself

```
 nano ~/.config/yarn/global/package.json <- add the package here using nano or any other text editor

 yarn global add <- to update everything
```